# “MySQL LIMIT @a ”has a syntax

Tags: mysql

When I run the following code, it give me a syntax callback.

```
SET @c = 1;

SELECT delay_time
FROM net_delay

ORDER BY delay_time
LIMIT @c;
```

But I want to give `LIMIT` a variable. Because only when my software is running, I will know what the `@c` is.（It seems that I allow the user to input the value of `@c`）. So how can I implement my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this? Try it;)

```
SET @c = 1;
prepare stmt from 'SELECT delay_time FROM net_delay ORDER BY delay_time LIMIT ?';
execute stmt using @c;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```